# How to link words in an HTML string and assign them @click method in VueJS 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, event-handling, vue-component

I have a array of strings in which I want to linkify certain words like "User object", "Promise", etc like this:

```
var strings = ['This returns a promise containing a User Object that has the id', 'next string']
```

This needs to be rendered like this

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item" v-for="str in strings" v-html="str"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is I want to replace words like "User object", "Promise" and bind them to a `@click` event that my app can handle.

So if it were rendered like I want it to be, it would be something like this (the same v-for loop above rendered manually)

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">This returns a <a href="#" @click.prevent="help('promise');">promise</a> containing a <a href="#" @click.prevent="help('User object');">User object</a> that has the id</div>
    <div class="item">next string</div>
 </div>
```

I tried doing this but it doesn't bind the `@click` event

```
methods: {
    linkify(str) {
       return str.replace(/user object/, '<a href="#" @click="help">User object</a>');
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Very interesting question, and honeslty I am new to Vue too. This might be helpful https://css-tricks.com/creating-vue-js-component-instances-programmatically/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/565467/ This is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Okay figured it out. **If somebody has a better way to do it please answer too!**

```
Vue.component('linkify', {
    props: ['value', 'words'],
    template: `<span :is="html"></span>`,
    data() {
        return {
            html: Vue.compile('<span>' + this.value.replace(new RegExp('(' + this.words.join('|') + ')', 'g'), `<a href="#" @click.prevent="$parent.$emit('click', '$1')"><code>$1</code></a>`) + '</span>'),
        }
    }
});
```

Now all I need to do in the main app is this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item" v-for="str in strings">
        <linkify :value="str" :words="['user object', 'promise']" @click="help"></linkify>
    </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately this only works with full version of Vue (which has the compile function)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a component that takes in a string for the full message and a string for the text to replace with a link and renders a span with that message with the link text wrapped in a `<a>` tag:

```js
Vue.component('linkify', {
  template: '#linkify-template',
  props: {
    value: { type: String },
    linkText: { type: String }
  },
  computed: {
    before() {
      return this.value.split(this.linkText)[0];
    },
    after() {
      return this.value.split(this.linkText)[1];
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'This returns a promise containing a User Object that has the id',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    foo() {
      console.log('clicked')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="linkify-template">
  <span>
    {{ before }}
    <a href="#" @click.prevent="$emit('click')">
      <code>{{ linkText }}</code>
    </a>
    {{ after }}
  </span>
</script>

<div id="app">
  <linkify link-text="User Object" :value="message" @click="foo"></linkify>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Will this be able to handle multiple keywords in a string with the possibility of same keyword appearing more than once?